# FadeIn function throwing uncaught reference error. Do I have to declare var?

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

I can't seem to get a particular area of my code to fadeIn when clicking a button.

I have set all `#new1-post` to hidden and I have linked jQuery 3.4.1. Please help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button1").button().click(function() {
    $("#new1-post").fadeIn();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-post-outer">
  <button class="button1" onClick="fadeIn();">Create New Post</button>
  <div class="new-post-mid">
    <form class=a bc>
      <label> New Post: </label><br>
      <input type="text" id="new1-post" class="new-post-title" placeholder="Title">
      <input type="text" id="new1-post" class="new-post" placeholder="Write The Body Of Your Post Here..."><br>
      <label> URL: </label><br>
      <input type="url" id="new-1post" class="new-post-url" placeholder="Please paste relevant URL here"><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the console. You've got missing braces and parentheses in your JS.

Comment: `I have set all #new1-post to hidden`. Id attribute values have to be unique in the DOM. If you have multiple elements with the same `id`, that's a problem. Use a class to group elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to use "onClick" attribute of Button tag or ".click()" in jquery.
And the other important point, "you cannot use same id for two or more items, an Id have to be always unique".

And put all the code to be fadeIn in a single div(better code practice).